# How to provide a body to a manually called https cloud function?

Tags: https, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have an HTTPS onRequest function that expects an argument inside the req.body. I am calling this function from a cloud task and because of that, I have to define a httpRequest like so:

```js
//this is the request:
    const task: tasks.protos.google.cloud.tasks.v2.ITask = {
        httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            url,
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        },
        scheduleTime: {
            seconds:  7200 + Date.now() / 1000
        }
    }
```

```js
//this is my function
functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     const payload = req.body as IScrapeTaskArguments;
});
```

This works as intended but I would like to be able to call this function manually.

How can I define the requests body if I want to manually test the function (call it from the browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an add-on or using a website tool, you cannot manually create HTTP POST requests. The browser address bar will only issue HTTP GET requests.

A very popular developer tool is [Postman](https://www.postman.com/). This runs in the browser and as an installable app.

Developers also use the CLI tools such as [curl](https://curl.se/). Curl is an amazing tool that you must have in your toolbox.